# what api to use to find all code changes for a github repository?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am not sure if my question is too broad. I am new to using github api. I need to find out all code changes w.r.t repository. How do I acheive this using github API? I went through the API list and couldn't find anything related to this. Should I use some other way apart from the github APIs to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "all code changes"? Every commit?

Comment: Yes...Code changes w.r.t every commit.

Answer (score -1):

The API for this is called ...

### git

Serioulsy, git is all about retrieving changes from repositories... what functionality are you looking for that is not part of git itself?
(Plus, it will work with other repositories than github, too!)